# Injecting jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm a bit practicing injecting jQuery into different sites to see how my code works and I came across this situation that I can't seem to figure out why this one doesn't want to accept my injection even if it is placed in the header and says successful.

Here's the code I'm trying to inject:

```
var fileref = document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js");

if (document.getElementsByTagName("head") != undefined)
{
    console.log("Adding jQuery to head");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
else 
{
    console.log("Adding jQuery to document");
    document.appendChild(fileref);
}
```

It usually works on different websites but on that website, I am getting this as result, why?

[image: photo of the selector]

[image: Photo of chrome console]

Comment: Your code injects Angular, not jQuery. Did you post the wrong code?

Comment: But correct me if I am wrong but doesn't AngularJS contain jquery?

Comment: I don't know, I've never used it. I would expect it to require you to load jQuery first, but maybe it loads it automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're injecting jQuery into a site that already loads jQuery. But it's using an older version of jQuery than the version you injected. Their code uses `.live()`, which was removed in jQuery 1.9. You've apparently injected at least 1.9, so now when their code tries to use `.live()` it gets an error.

Comment: Ok so if i understood correctly, to fix this, I should just try using an older version?

Comment: Or maybe you shouldn't be injecting code into other websites, since it's hard to predict what the dependencies will be. Or you could use `jQuery.noConflict()` to allow multiple versions to coexist.

Comment: ok so it did work when i changed it to:   fileref.setAttribute("src", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js");

Answer (score 1):

If you open the site:
**https://greenbuyback.com/cell-phones/?limit=all&model=htc**
without injecting  anything you will see the same error in the console.

This is up to the library **https://greenbuyback.com/skin/frontend/default/gbb/js/jm.script.js** that requires jQuery 1.8.3. Such version of jQuery is included after the jQuery version 1.10.2. It seems a workaround to solve this compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. You need to use .on(). Replace .live() and place correct parameters. Read about how to use .on()

The main difference is thet you need to call from parent and then select current object. Like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function() { /* do stuff */ });
```

in your case selector is

```
("#ja-mainnav .btn-toggle")
```

For some very random and rear rease which still I do not know. By the way, I investigate bug with

```
$ == undefined or jquery == undefine
```

Also you can check old .live

```
if(jQuery && !jQuery.fn.live) {
    jQuery.fn.live = function(evt, func) {
        $('body').on(evt, this.selector, func);
    }
}
```

from more than two years. what a shame for me. injected jquery have problem. Now here is the first one which at least will help you

```
function _isJqLoad() {
    return !(typeof jQuery == 'undefined') && !(typeof $ == 'undefined');
}
```

Before call any jquery even simple document ready you can check and try to inject

```
if (_isJQLoad()){

     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
          // call js
      });
}
else{

   // try to inject or you can do something

}
```